# CSS not linking properly

Tags: html, css

I'm making a quick webpage with the following HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Summer CTF</title>
        <link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ctf.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Harris Summer 2017 CTF</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Points</td>
                <td>Flags Acquired</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John Doe</td>
                <td>2.5</td>
                <td><a href="flag1.html">#1</a>, <a href="flag6.html">#6</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jane Doe</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><a href="flag2.html">#2</a>, <a href="flag3.html">#3</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

However the css, which is properly saved in the same directory as the html, is not getting linked to the html. I used style tags just to see if css won't show up in my browser but that worked. These are all locally stored.

EDIT: ctf.css contains the following code

```
* {
    color: blue;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: red;
}

table, tr, td {
    border: 1px black solid;
}
```

Comment: what goes in your ctf.css? make sure you don't write style tags in there

Comment: Nothing. Also if I inspect the source code the href properly links to the css.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic due to a  typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change

```
<link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ctf.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ctf.css">
```